# How to use 'dotnet restore' with a feed that need to authenticate with?

Tags: .net, nuget

My project uses a custom feed that I need to authenticate to before using it.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore tells me that `--interactive` flag should be used. However, that doesn't change anything. I'm getting errors:

> /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/NuGet.targets(124,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://myproject.pkgs.visualstudio.com/_packaging/MyFeed/nuget/v3/inde
>   x.json. [/home/xyx/code/MyApp.csproj]
>   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/3.1.201/NuGet.targets(124,5): error :   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized). [/home/xyx/code/MyApp.csproj]

How to I authorize to my feed?

Comment: I believe you want to use `dotnet nuget add source`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-add-source to set up your username and password.

Comment: I see this allows adding nuget sources. How should I use it if I already have my source added to NuGet.Config? I tried multiple ways, but failed.

Comment: I do not want to store my credentials in a file that is in git repository

Comment: Your credentials will be stored in C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config, not in your git repository. Also your password will be encrypted. This is the way I'm using it. I don't know about any other options.

Answer (score 26):

To make dotnet ask you for credentials, you need to install https://github.com/microsoft/artifacts-credprovider. It solves the problem.

Comment: This is what (finally) helped me!

Comment: FYI sometimes even this doesn't help for reasons specified in [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/22987), so adding `-v diag` on top of the instructions in the credprovider might be necessary.

Comment: To summarize the GitHub documentation, for Windows you just need to run `iex "& { $(irm https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.ps1) } -AddNetfx"` in command line before `dotnet restore --interactive`