# How to authenticate with private nuget package source while running dotnet restore

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I am trying to run `dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config my-solution.sln` on the command line to restore packages from a private nuget source but I am unable to authenticate with the private nuget and I am getting this error:

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://my.private.nuget/source/FindPackagesById()?semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
```

However I am able to successfully restore packages from `visual studio`, when I tried nuget package restore from `visual studio`, I got a prompt asking for credentials and after adding the creds the restore happened correctly.

I am trying to figure out where I need to add the credentials for the private nuget while I am restoring through the command line.

Comment: Have you tried passing `--interactive`?

Comment: No, can you show me an example of how I can pass --interactive along with dotnet restore @kit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use 'dotnet restore' with a feed that need to authenticate with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61386458/how-to-use-dotnet-restore-with-a-feed-that-need-to-authenticate-with)

Comment: In your case it would be `dotnet restore --configfile NuGet.config my-solution.sln`, but I suggest looking at the question the other commenter posted.

Comment: --interactive didnt help. I have answered my own question about how I solved it without installing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding my nuget credentials in the `Nuget.config` file, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file)
to see how to properly format your `Nuget.config` file as for `nuget 4.6` and below there is a different format for adding credentials to the `Nuget.config` than how it is for the newer versions.

Comment: Could you show an example?