dotnet restore and AzureDevops private feed in WSL
I need to run an Asp.Net Core application in WSL (Ubuntu 22.04), I'm trying to execute command:

dotnet restore

to restore my nuget packages from default nuget.org and from my private feed on Azure Devops Server 2019. I set the feed in NuGet.config file with credentials and API key like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="Nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"/>
        <add key="MyFeed" value="https://devops.myfeed.com/tfs/company/_packaging/CompanyPackages/nuget/v3/index.json"/>
    </packageSources>
    <packageSourceCredentials>
        <MyFeed>
            <add key="Username" value="DOMAIN\User"/>
            <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="PATforPackages"/>
        </MyFeed>
    </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>

But i always get an 401 Unauthorized error. Has anyone had the same problem? How can I solve it?
Thanks
UPDATE
This is the log stack trace:

1>/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/8.0.107/NuGet.targets(156,5): error : Unable to
load the service index for source
https://devops.myfeed.com/tfs/company/_packaging/CompanyPackages/nuget/v3/index.json.
......... /usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/8.0.107/NuGet.targets(156,5): error :
Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
[/mnt/c/Users/..../MyProject.proj.csproj]  Assembly loaded during
TaskRun (NuGet.Build.Tasks.RestoreTask):
System.Diagnostics.StackTrace, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a (location:
/usr/lib/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/8.0.7/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll,
MVID: 7d4e9037-cc6f-43b1-8255-6608ac20f6b1, AppDomain: [Default])
NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the
service index for source
https://devops.myfeed.com/tfs/company/_packaging/CompanyPackages/nuget/v3/index.json.
---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).    at
System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()     at
NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<>c__DisplayClass15_01.<<GetAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location ---     at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func2 action, CancellationToken token)     at
NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String
filePath, Func2 action, CancellationToken token)     at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetAsync[T](HttpSourceCachedRequest request, Func2 processAsync, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)    at
NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.GetServiceIndexResourceV3(SourceRepository
source, DateTime utcNow, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)    ---
End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.GetServiceIndexResourceV3(SourceRepository
source, DateTime utcNow, ILogger log, CancellationToken token)    at
NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.TryCreate(SourceRepository
source, CancellationToken token)  at
NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T](CancellationToken
token)    at
NuGet.Protocol.Providers.VulnerabilityInfoResourceV3Provider.TryCreate(SourceRepository
source, CancellationToken token)  at
NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T](CancellationToken
token)    at
NuGet.Commands.VulnerabilityInformationProvider.GetVulnerabilityInfoAsync()
at
NuGet.Commands.VulnerabilityInformationProvider.GetVulnerabilityInformationAsync(CancellationToken
cancellationToken)    at
NuGet.Commands.Restore.Utility.AuditUtility.GetAllVulnerabilityDataAsync(CancellationToken
cancellationToken)    at
NuGet.Commands.Restore.Utility.AuditUtility.CheckPackageVulnerabilitiesAsync(CancellationToken
cancellationToken)    at
NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.PerformAuditAsync(EnabledValue
enableAudit, IEnumerable1 graphs, TelemetryActivity telemetry, CancellationToken token)  at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.PerformAuditAsync(EnabledValue enableAudit, IEnumerable1 graphs, TelemetryActivity telemetry,
CancellationToken token)  at
NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.PerformAuditAsync(EnabledValue
enableAudit, IEnumerable1 graphs, TelemetryActivity telemetry, CancellationToken token)  at NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.PerformAuditAsync(EnabledValue enableAudit, IEnumerable1 graphs, TelemetryActivity telemetry,
CancellationToken token)  at
NuGet.Commands.Restore.Utility.AuditUtility.CheckPackageVulnerabilitiesAsync(CancellationToken
cancellationToken)    at
NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommand.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken token)
at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.ExecuteAsync(RestoreSummaryRequest
summaryRequest, CancellationToken token)  at
NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.ExecuteAsync(RestoreSummaryRequest
summaryRequest, CancellationToken token)  at
NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.ExecuteAndCommitAsync(RestoreSummaryRequest
summaryRequest, IRestoreProgressReporter progressReporter,
CancellationToken token)  at
NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.CompleteTaskAsync(List1 restoreTasks) at NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.RunAsync(IEnumerable1
restoreRequests, RestoreArgs restoreArgs, CancellationToken token)    at
NuGet.Commands.RestoreRunner.RunAsync(RestoreArgs restoreContext,
CancellationToken token)  at
NuGet.Build.Tasks.BuildTasksUtility.RestoreAsync(DependencyGraphSpec
dependencyGraphSpec, Boolean interactive, Boolean recursive, Boolean
noCache, Boolean ignoreFailedSources, Boolean disableParallel, Boolean
force, Boolean forceEvaluate, Boolean hideWarningsAndErrors, Boolean
restorePC, Boolean cleanupAssetsForUnsupportedProjects, ILogger log,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)  at
NuGet.Build.Tasks.RestoreTask.ExecuteAsync(ILogger log)

UPDATE
I updated the NuGet.Config file as above
UPDATE 2
The solution recommended by @wade zhou - MSFT to use this configuration
--valid-authentication-types basic

with the PAT (Personal Access Token) works perfectly. Thanks

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61389452/558486

i have installed the plugn, when i run dotnet restore i get this: 'The plugin credential provider could not acquire credentials. Authentication may require manual action. Consider re-running the command with --interactive for dotnet' but when i run dotnet restore --interactive i have 401 and nothing happens

The private feed is from local ADO server 2019, could you please clarify where do you run the pipeline to restore? On DevOps cloud service, or same local ADO server? And in nuget.config, did you put the PAT value for ClearTextPassword? and does the user(who generated PAT) has permission on the private feed?

I run the command dotnet restore from my machine in WSL, i have the PAT with package scope and i have the permission to access to private feed.


But i always get an 401 Unauthorized error.

It appears you have disabled the DevOps feed myfeed in Nuget.Config. Please remove it from <disabledPackageSources> section.

In addtion, the 401 error indicates the user doesn't have permission or PAT is not correct. please follow below items to check:

Make sure the user has permission on the DevOps feed.


Generate a new PAT token with package read scope at least. Put it in the nuget.config.



Specify the Nuget.config file in the command:
$ dotnet restore <project>.csproj --configfile NuGet.config --verbosity detailed


In WSL, make sure it can access the target Azure devops server site.
The restore result on my side for your reference:


Thanks first of all for the help, however nothing to be done, I followed all the steps but without success. Now even when I run the dotnet restore it seems to go in a loop with the error.

I also tried with curl to read the json from the feed url and the only way to do it is to use the --ntlm option

Go to target Feed -> Connect to Feed -> dotnet page-> Others tab on the right page, it shows how to use PAT to authenticate. Try with dotnet nuget update source nugetfeed --valid-authentication-types basic --username "nugetfeed" --password [Personal Access Token] and then dotnet restore --interactive, will it work?

I have this error: "Encryption is not supported on non-Windows platforms.

As per the link, could you double check if you have put the PAT explictly as the value for ClearTextPassword in nuget.config? The command works on my side in WSL.

@pampua84, may i know if all setting checked as above? The error Encryption is not supported on non-Windows platforms, please check the link above, and you can directly put the PAT as ClearTextPassword in nuget.config.

I added the PAT as a clear password in the NuGet.Config file as you indicated, but it continues to give me Unauthorized, while if Windows works. Is there a way to enable logs on Azure DevOps to understand the reason for this 401? Unfortunately at the moment the logs on the DevOps file do not say anything. Thanks

You are NOT running pipeline to restore, right? I'm afraid there's no log from DevOps side since it's only a nuget feed used. To narrow down the issue, could you please create a public devops nuget  feed which doesn't require authentication(from public project), use it in nuget.config, will it access successfully?

I am very sorry, I had missed this configuration --valid-authentication-types basic. With PAT and basic authentication everything works correctly. Thank you very much and sorry again

Thanks for the update, glad to know it's resolved! Happy coding!
